# "move up the school" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "As he **moved up the school**, he gathered about him a group of dedicated friends; I call them that, for want of a better term, although as I have already indicated, Riddle undoubtedly felt no affection for any of them.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince by J.K. Rowling</sub>

I'm not sure what "moved up the school" is supposed to mean. Is it *his grade getting higher* or something?

Comment: No - it's just a reference to the passing of time. He started as a first-year student, then "moved up" to year two, year three, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is it a common phrase? It seems to me that *As he moved up in the school* makes more sense.

Comment: @dan  The phrase is common, but using it to describe going from one school year to the next seems particularly British.  I think *"advance"* might be more common in the U.S., and possibly elsewhere.

Comment: @dan: It's much the same as [*moved up (through) the ranks*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moved+up+the+ranks%2Cmoved+up+through+the+ranks&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmoved%20up%20the%20ranks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoved%20up%20through%20the%20ranks%3B%2Cc0) (e.g. - within the armed forces), where as that link shows, the modern tendency (BrE ***and*** AmE) is increasingly to drop the "unnecessary" preposition completely.

Comment: @Andrew So, 'school' here refers to *school years*?

Comment: @dan In the real-world version of this type of school in the UK, the students often physically "move" to a different set of classrooms and a different set of teachers each year. They also "move" to different accommodation (particularly, different dormitories) in the boarding parts of the school. Obviously this doesn't apply to *everything,* e.g. at Hogwarts there is only one dining hall for all students, but it explains the use of the word.

Comment: @dan  Yes; however I'm American so I can't speak for what life is like in a typical British boarding school on which "Harry Potter" is based. As others have said, there may actually be some physical change in location from year to year, implying "movement".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means "As he moved from year 1, to year 2, and ultimately to the sixth form"

You move up the school automatically in Hogwarts (as in the rest of the UK education system) there is no retaking of years, and test required to move up at the end of each year. It is not a very common phrase but I have no difficulty understanding it.